# how to exclude IDs (string) that are not in the defined range

Tags: expression, transformation, informatica-powercenter

Please, help me to find the right formula for expression transformation in informatica. I need to exclude all Product_IDs that are not in the range of [B1,B40]. There is also Product_IDs that are > B40. The Product_ID is string, so I cannot simply write for example for Check_Out Port:

```
IIF (Produkt_ID > 'P40', 'error', 'no_error')
```

Comment: Do you have a complete range of the Product_Ids you have ? It is not possible to say value > B40 ... It doesn't mean anything

Comment: Your question mentions id's with a 'B', but your code uses an example with 'P'. Is that a typo of is B not the only letter you need to include/exclude?

Answer (score 0):

You could separate out product ID letter into v_P_ID_L and product ID number into v_P_ID_NO, one a string a number. v_P_ID_L expression is: SUBSTR( Produkt_ID, 1,1)
v_P_ID_NO expression is: SUBSTR(Produkt_ID,2)

Then the IIF above becomes

IIF (V_P_ID_L = 'B' AND (v_P_ID_NO  <= 40), 'no error', 'error')